# How do I get a variable inside a struct in a header file? C++

Tags: c++, variables, struct

Basically one of my header files has been changed, and the function to return certain variables in it has been removed and I have no idea how to get the variables now. Can any please shed some light on the same.

The function `getX()` and `getY()` has been removed from the header file, and I am not allowed to add/modify the header file in any way. Is there a way I can still get the values of x and y from my `main.cpp`?:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point ()                {   x = NULL;   y = NULL;   }
    Point (int x1, int y1)  {   x = x1;     y = y1;     }
    ~Point (void)           {   }


    Point & operator= (const Point &p)
    {   x = p.x;    y = p.y;    return (*this);     }

    bool operator== (const Point &p)
    {   return ( (x == p.x) && (y == p.y) );        } 

    bool operator!= (const Point &p)
    {   return ( (x != p.x) || (y != p.y) );        } 

    // 2 points are 'connected' but 'different' if they : 
    // i)  share the same 'x' but adjacent 'y' values, OR
    // ii) share the same 'y' but adjacent 'x' values!!
    bool isConnected (Point &p)
    {
        return (    ((x == p.x) && ( ((y-1) == p.y) || ((y+1) == p.y) )) || 
                    ((y == p.y) && ( ((x-1) == p.x) || ((x+1) == p.x) ))
               );
    }

    void display (std::ostream &outputStream=std::cout)     
    {   outputStream << "[" << x << ", " << y << "]";   }


    ============================================================
    // This two functions are now removed. =====================
    ============================================================
    int getX() // Removed.
    {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() // Removed.
    {
        return y;
    }

};
```

The part where I previously used these two functions:

```
int deadendX = pointOne.getX();
int deadendY = pointOne.getY();
```

So is there a way to do it now that the functions are removed from the header file? Like can I write some functions in my main.cpp to do this?

Comment: It's a struct. The members are public. A good book list is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
int deadendX = pointOne.x;
int deadendY = pointOne.y;
```

x and y are public member variables of Point, so they are accessible to you.

Comment: Oh it was that simple! Thanks a lot! Works well.

Answer (score 3):

You can access public struct/class members the same way, wether they are data members or methods. So just write this:

```
int deadendX = pointOne.x;
int deadendY = pointOne.y;
```